# Adapter with hasStableIds using GUIDs or Strings as Ids

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I'm implementing a custom `ArrayAdapter<T>`, and I want to set the `hasStableIds` to true. But the ids of my T items are **Strings** and the `getItemId` method returns **longs**.

So, what I am currently doing is:

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return this.getItem(position).getId().hashCode();
}
```

Where `getId()` returns a String.

Is this the correct solution for using String ids?
In particular, for this case, the String Ids are GUIDs, is there a better option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to use the `hashCode()` because this way, two different GUIDS might result in the same ID.

Just code a mapping. Something like this...

```
private static class GuidToIdMap {
    private final Map<String, Long> guidToIdMapping = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    private final Map<Long, String> idToGuidMapping = new HashMap<Long, String>();

    private long idGenerator = 0;

    public long getIdByGuid(final String guid) {
        if ( ! guidToIdMapping.containsKey(guid)) {
            final long id = idGenerator++;
            guidToIdMapping.put(guid, id);
            idToGuidMapping.put(id,   guid);
        }
        return guidToIdMapping.get(guid);
    }

    public String getGuidById(final long id) {
        if (idToGuidMapping.containsKey(id)) {
            return idToGuidMapping.get(id);
        }
        return null;
    }
}


private final GuidToIdMap guidToIdMap = new GuidToIdMap();

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    final String guid = this.getItem(position).getId();
    return guidToIdMap.getIdByGuid(guid);
}

// Use guidToIdMap.getGuidById(id) where the Android Framework passes you the generated id
```

Performance impact will be negligible....

Comment: Use 
    final long id = new Random().nextLong(); 
instead of idGenerator variable. It's possible to get duplicate ids with idGenerator.

Comment: @rajeswariratala please explain how it would be possible to get duplicates for 'idGenerator'?!

Comment: Since it is not synchronized, I was getting duplicates. you can either use an atomiclong and getAndIncrement() or random long.

Comment: Odd. Most likely you did not post a GUI task on the [Android UI thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)). Consider [AsyncTasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#AsyncTask) for doing background work for which the result needs to be processed by the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

It is ok for as long as it is true that the returned id keeps being the same for same object after changes and it's unique as described in javadoc for hasStableIds

Comment: @Niels sure! But my phrase is right anyway. Same string is same hash and that is inherent to java even when it is not the same string but accidentally has the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
    return UUID.getLeastSignificantBits()

P/s: You probably should not. A `long`'s size is 8 bytes whereas an UUID's size 16 bytes. Hence an `UUID` can not be stored in a `long`. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

> The identifier size and generation process need to be selected so as to make this sufficiently improbable in practice. 
>   Therefore, two different UUIDs can have the same `leastSignificantBits`.

Answer (score -1):

No you are incorrect getItemId has tow method signatures and one of them returns long per docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)

Comment: Actually, there is only one getItemId method and it returns long, so please check your information before posting.